# Parsing yaml file using snakeyaml with integer as key

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to parse a yaml file that I did not create, and one that I cannot edit. The structure of the file is

```
681:
  activities:
    copying:
      time: 480
    manufacturing:
      materials:
      - quantity: 86
        typeID: 38
      products:
      - quantity: 1
        typeID: 165
      time: 600
    research_material:
      time: 210
    research_time:
      time: 210
  blueprintTypeID: 681
  maxProductionLimit: 300
```

The file is ~144,000 lines in length, each following the aforementioned structure. The problem I'm having is, because it's being parsed into POJOs using reflection, the very first key (in this case `681:`) in the structure is an integer. Fields in Java cannot be named solely a numerical value, so when the parsing happens, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint; exception=Cannot create property=682 for JavaBean=org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint@2446bd09; No JavaBean properties found in org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    681:
    ^
```

Is there a way to prevent the snakeyaml from parsing the value as an integer, and instead parse it as a string? I've tried using a custom resolver, and disabling resolving of integers all together, and that still did not work.

Comment: Have you tried the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Tutorial)? What are the problems you experience?

Comment: Yes I've tried the tutorial. It was the first thing I looked into. The problem that I've having is that the doing `Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Foo.class));` then subsequently `yaml.loadAll(fileInputStream);` I get a `Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint; exception=Cannot create property=681 for JavaBean=org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint@2446bd09; No JavaBean properties found in org.zephyrion.eve.assetmanager.Blueprint
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    681:` exception, because the first tag is an integer, not a String.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a solution that doesn't require changing the YAML file, yes? (Otherwise, you could just replace `681:` with `'681':` or `!!str 681:` using some script).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My solution because I couldn't figure out to do it, was to make a bunch of static factory methods, and broke down each section into a new object.

Comment: Not only does this need to be fixed for custom YAML files, but as it turns out that in  the OpenAPI YAML specification when you want to specify return values for RESTful requests, the returnvalues are not quoted. For example, in an OpenAPI 3 spec on SwaggerHub, the return codes sre 200: or 404:. They are *not* '200': or '400': Anyone creating YAML for OpenAPI will need a solution to this problem -- unless you want to get the folks doing OpenAPI to change the specification...