# How to parse Integer value as keys in YAML File

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am running a spring boot project where I need to parse an erro code dynamically, but I have realised that if the key is of integer type, it return null. Is there a way to parse Integer Keys in YAML file

Parsing This property doesnt work

```
errorcode:
     00001: An error occurred whilst trying to process your request. We would like to apologise for the inconvenience.
```

Howver Parsing This property work

```
errorcode:
  ONE: An error occurred whilst trying to process your request. We would like to apologise for the inconvenience.
```

I am trying to read this property using

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

error= environment.getProperty("errorcode.ONE") Works
error= environment.getProperty("errorcode.00001") --Doesn't works
```

So in nutshell, if an integer has been used as a key, YAML file is returning value as null. One workaround is to use the key this way as shown below, but any better ideas?

```
error
  code-001:
```

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687844/parsing-yaml-file-using-snakeyaml-with-integer-as-key

Comment: I don't have enough information to see which YAML processor is used. Assuming SnakeYAML, you should note that it loads the `00001` as a simple `1`, so you could try `"errorcode.1"`. Instead of assuming it gets converted to null, you could als try debugging and output the complete data.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by specifying that number as string in yaml. like,

errorcode:

```
'00001': An error occurred whilst trying to process your request. We would like to apologise for the inconvenience.
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Read all string from the yaml and replace the integer value with non integer value. Descerialize the class with non integer value as variable.